# Get access to eclipse's console inside a docker

Tags: java, docker

How can I get an access to console in eclipse inside the docker container?
I run commands in JAVA to open docker container and to open telnet session, but I'm not able to sen any other command in my script. I can type commands in eclipse by a hand, but I need to automate this process. How can I switch to the Eclipse's console?

```java
public void executeCommands() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        File tempScript = createTempScript();

        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", tempScript.toString());
            pb.inheritIO();
            Process process = pb.start();
            process.waitFor();
        } finally {
            tempScript.delete();
        }
}

public File createTempScript() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        File tempScript = File.createTempFile("script", null);

        Writer streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(
                tempScript));
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(streamWriter);

        printWriter.println("#!/bin/bash");
        printWriter.println("echo test1234| sudo -S pwd");
        printWriter.println("sudo docker exec -i MyconteinerID telnet localhost 2000"); 
        printWriter.println("testcommand");

        printWriter.close();

        return tempScript;
}
```

I tried also to use a multiple commands in a single row. Everything works good, but the last command, which need to be run in telnet won't execute.

```
printWriter.println("whoami; ls; echo test1234| sudo -S pwd; sudo docker exec -i MycontainerID telnet localhost 2000; testCommand");
```

Comment: You are attacking this problem the wrong way as I see it, can't you now just connect to the telnet port via a socket and send your command there? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3763558/5047819

Comment: @AndersLindgren You solution would be good, but I have no idea how can I open the socket inside the docker's container.

Comment: Why do you need to access the docker container at all? And why though a Java program?

Comment: @AndersLindgren  because I need to run telent command from there. Java - because I need to automate this process for testing purposes.

Comment: @AndersLindgren I solved the problem. There is no need to access docker. I can simply connect with telnet stright from the terminal. But I'm still curious how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You know that telnet is just a command to send data to via a socket (host + port). If you look at the example in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3763558/5047819) it will do just that.

telnet is not very good command to use in automation either, so in this case netcat could be a better choice. This calls for netcat to be installed (apt install netcat or similar). Read the man page for more info on how to use it.

If you really would like to run bash from java try changing your program to something like this.

```java
printWriter.println("whoami; ls; printf \"testCommand\\r\\n\" | nc localhost 2000");
```